# SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK Request language

Tags: s4sdk

We are using the SDK to call an API which has localized attributes. Testing this API via POSTMAN if we set the accept-language header we get the localized fields.
Is there a similar way to obtain the localized fields using the ODataQueryBuilder?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, it would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `withHeader` method of the `ODataQueryBuilder`.

For SAP S/4HANA, you can provide a `sap-language` header.